# How to use Ctrl + D to end input from user on C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

(I'm on Windows using VS Code)

I'm trying to take many lines of input from a user and input must end when user hits 'Ctrl + D' and then it must continue onto rest of code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

string x, input, output, choice;

cin >> x;
cin >> choice:

getline(cin , input) ;                // need this part to end when user hits Ctrl + D and i 
                                         need more than one line of input

// Rest of my code already completed 

}
```

Comment: You need to use Window keyboard event https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/keyboard-input#keyboard-state

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl D corresponds to the ASCII character EOT, which has decimal value 4. So,
`getline(cin, input, '\x04');`
This works for multiple lines, and getline will return after you do Ctrl D then enter, stripping Ctrl D and anything you typed after it before enter from input.